# AngularJS watch if element is visible

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to execute a function when an element becomes visible. For example when a user scrolls down the page and an element becomes visible I want to execute a function.

Is this possible?

Comment: Nothing to do with AngularJS. What have you tried? Have you looked into `$(element).offset()`? Comparing this to the page scroll offset plus the page height should do the trick.

Comment: I think I'm going to use this: https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear but I'm interested in why you think this has nothing to do with angular :)

Comment: Did not know of `jQuery.appear`, though it looks like it's doing exactly that, compares offsets. Your issue has to do with DOM inspection and manipulation, something jQuery is best at for example. AngularJS uses a subset of jQuery called jQLite for DOM inspection and manipulation, it does not try to replace it in any way. Tagging your question as "angularjs" related is simply too restrictive. Even "jQuery" would be restrictive in my opinion, as DOM element offsets are something native, not restricted to jQuery, or Angular.